Rails 7 button_to with a confirm message but processed as HTML
Rails 7 default all actions to TURBO_STREAM processing.
Thus, if one wants to process as HTML, one would add a data attribute to a button_to tag  with  data: { turbo: false }
However, how does one, in the case of a delete action, generate a confirm message?
data: { turbo_confirm: t('promotion.delete_sure'), turbo: false }
data: { confirm: t('promotion.delete_sure'), turbo: false }

both of these do not go through the confirmation stage but execute directly (and process as HTML.

if you want to process as HTML you can just respond with html in a controller.

I don't see how that can be done, because the headers are set by the time the controller starts. Processing by .. as TURBO_STREAM

sure, but TURBO_STREAM can handle both turbo_stream and html responses.

yeah, I did not mention in the question that I need to re-direct.  There's complex multiple object logic that requires it. Thus, rails is looking for a turbo_stream.erb file (returning content missing).  Got to resolve this upstream.

content missing is a turbo frame error, maybe all you need is data: {turbo_frame: "_top"} to redirect out of the frame.

that was on the nose !  I never understood the concept of navigating 'Into or Out of a Frame' as per the docs, sort of being thrown off by HTML terminology that has a different usage.  I bow in recognition!

The confirmation dialog is almost completely unrelated to the request sent by the link/button.
Turbo Drive adds an event handler to the document which listens for click events on interactive elements with the data-turbo-confirm and will fire the browsers confirm method by default.
Depending on if this method returns true of false the original event (click/submission) will be prevented or allowed to propogate.
data-confirm was the equivilent for the old Rails UJS handler which Turbo replaces. It does nothing unless you have Rails UJS present on the page.
data-turbo="false" disables Turbo Drive on links and forms including descendants. This also disables the data-turbo-confirm handler.
Also note that when using button_to you need to add the data attribute to the form that it uses internally:
<%= button_to "Delete post", post, method: :delete, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } } %>

See:

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality

